# Defining variables with key and value from a dictionary in a function?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a lot of data coming in dictionaries. My code runs some equations that for clarity have the same names as the dictionary keys.
Lets say weight = density * volume where data['density'] is the dictionary entry.

I need a compact way to define all this variables inside the scope of my function without writing too many lines and avoiding writing data['whatever'] on every line of my equations.

I've tried this but does not work on the framework of the function.

```py
for key in data:
    exec("%s = %s" % (key, data[key]))
```

works fine outside the function

```py
def weights(data):
    #this is what I would like
    for key in data:
        key = data[key]

    W1 = rho1 * V1
    W2 = rho2 * V2
    #where rho and V are values found in the dictionary
```

For more clarity, I am doing this by hand and taking many lines to do it.
The name of the key is the name of the variable as you can see.
I would like a compact way of unpacking the dictionary without changing the entry data to the function.

```py
    crossAreaSteel = areas["crossAreaSteel"] * mmSqTOmSq
    crossAreaClad = areas["crossAreaClad"] * mmSqTOmSq
    crossAreaAntiCorr = areas["crossAreaAntiCorr"] * mmSqTOmSq
    crossAreaConcr = areas["crossAreaConcr"] * mmSqTOmSq
    crossAreaMarineGrow = areas["crossAreaMarineGrow"] * mmSqTOmSq
    crossAreaJointAntiCorr = areas["crossAreaJointAntiCorr"] * mmSqTOmSq
    crossAreaJointConcrete = areas["crossAreaJointConcrete"] * mmSqTOmSq
    crossAreaExternalPipe = areas["crossAreaExternalPipe"] * mmSqTOmSq
    crossAreaInternalPipe = areas["crossAreaInternalPipe"] * mmSqTOmSq
    rhoSteel = densities['rhoSteel']
    rhoClad = densities['rhoClad']
    rhoCoat = densities['rhoCoat']
```

Comment: You know `exec` is extremely risky right?

Comment: Also please provide an example dictionary and example output for that dictionary.

Comment: I kind of understand what you're asking, but then, also, I don't understand (it's not clear). "equations have the same names as dictionary keys", but "weight = density * volume" maps to `'density'`? Can you add [mcve] including an example of such a dict (with one or two entries should be sufficient) and how you're curently implementing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you know exactly what variables are needed for the function and you can modify how the function is called, you can use the `**` operator and keyword arguments to unpack the data when passing it to the function.

```py
def function_of_rhos(rho1, rho2, V1, V2, **kwargs):
    return (rho1 * V1, rho2 * V2)


my_args = {"rho1": 2, "rho2": 3, "V1": 0, "V2": 1}
my_args_with_extras = {
    "rho1": 2,
    "rho2": 3,
    "V1": 0,
    "V2": 1,
    "extra1": 4,
    "extra2": "yes",
}

my_args_with_missing = {"rho1": 2, "rho2": 3, "extra1": 4, "extra2": "yes"}

print(function_of_rhos(**my_args))
print(function_of_rhos(**my_args_with_extras))
print(function_of_rhos(**my_args_with_missing))
```

Yields

```
(0, 3)
(0, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(function_of_rhos(**my_args_with_missing))
TypeError: function_of_rhos() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'V1' and 'V2'
```

If you want to avoid the exception thrown in the last case, you could define the function to have default values that get used for things missing in the dict

```py
def function_of_rhos(rho1, rho2, V1=3, V2=2, **kwargs):
    return (rho1 * V1, rho2 * V2)
```